# How to automate git pull from remote repo

Tags: angular, git, github

Suppose a user is working on some angular project on system A having a remote repo on Github. I also have this project on a server which is also linked with that same repo.

If the user made some changes and then push to the remote repo using system A.

How the server system can automate the task of git pull. I mean how the server should know that there are changes pushed to remote that needs to be pulled automatically.

I read about hooks but I don't know how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: here is a [tutorial](https://www.jobsity.com/blog/automatic-pull-server) how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve the same is by using a cronjob.

This may be helpful for you in the future not just for automating a `git pull` but any of the tasks or triggers you wanna create.

Link: [cron-job](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux)